# The maximum row sum norm of a triangular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

$A$ is the matrix $\in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$ with
$$
a_{ij}=\begin{cases}
1&\text{ if } i=j,\\
-1&\text{ if } i<j,\\
0&\text{ if } i>j,
\end{cases}
$$
i.e. an upper triangular matrix. 
Now if $\kappa_{\infty} = \|A\|_{\infty}\|A^{-1}\|_{\infty}$ whereas $\|A\|_{\infty} = \max_{1\leq i \leq m} \sum_{j=1}^n|A_{ij}|$ I would like to show that $\kappa_{\infty}(A)= n2^{n-1}$.
Now, the only idea I have come up with so far is to write $A$ as identity matrix I minus the upper triangular matrix with only 1's over the main diagonal. But then I had no idea how to calculate the maximum norm of *this* matrix...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: When
\begin{align*}
A&=(a_{ij})_{i,j\leq n}=\left\{
\begin{array}{rl}
1 & i=j\\
-1 & i>j\\
0 & \text{else}
\end{array}\right.\\
A^{-1}&=(\tilde{a}_{ij})_{i,j \leq n }=\left\{
\begin{array}{rl}
1& i=j\\
0& j>1\\
2^{i-j-1} & i > j
\end{array}\right.
\end{align*}
As $\|A\|=n$ and $\|A^{-1}\|=2^{n-1}$ you should be able to calculate the condition.

You get those formulas when you compute the first few matrices.

Comment: Great I got it..the norm of A is obviously n since the first rows sum of absolute values always equates to n, and the norm of the inverse is also easy to see now. Thanks for help!